# CSS animation at the edges of my page making it change sizes

Tags: html, css, containers, jsx, overflow

I'm pretty sure the answer is simple, but I've been going at it for a while. I'm working on the landing page for a website where there are images stuck to both edges of the page simulating swaying leaves. My code seemed to be working quite well until I ran into a problem where only the swaying of the leaves on the right side of the page causes it to change sizes both horizontally and vertically and I get a scrollbar at the bottom of my page coming in and out as the animation executes.

Here is the structure of my JSX:

```
  <div className='app'>
      <div className='**wrapper**'>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='**maincontainer**'>
          <div className='**animleft**'>
            <img alt='left-folliage-1' >
            <img alt='left-folliage-2' >
            <img alt='left-folliage-3' >
            <img alt='left-folliage-4' >
          </div>
          <Hero />
          <div className='**animright**'>
            <img alt='right-folliage-2' >
            <img alt='right-folliage-1' >
            <img alt='right-folliage-3' >
            <img alt='right-folliage-4' >
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.maincontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

.wrapper {
  background-image: url('../assets/hero2.png');
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;  
}

.animleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.animright {
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}

.animleft img {
  position: absolute;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
  animation: leaf-sway 5s ease-in-out infinite;/* Apply the animation to my leaf imgs */
  left: -15px;

}

.animright img {
  position: absolute;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
  animation: leaf-sway 5s ease-in-out infinite;/* Apply the animation to my leaf imgs */
  right: -15px;

}


//repeat the following 7 times for each of the folliage images
.animleft img:nth-child(1) {
  top: -5%;
  max-width: 75vh;
 }
```

I am also using normalize CSS.

On the left it works as it should by hiding the overflow on the X axis but allowing it to overlap on the Y axis over other containers. On the right, not so much (pic related below). When the images of the leaves move with the animation, you can see the edges of the images, and as the animation executes, they push the page into the right.

[image: pic related here:]

I tried playing around with the position of the different elements and the width and height of both .animright, .maincontainer and .wrapper but nothing seems to be working. Its wither does not react to the changes or it completely sends the images into the far left.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the body selector to hide the overflow on the X axis which was not my best option since I wanted to find a way to match the left side of the elements.

```
body { 
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```